# Can't set both scale_size_continuous() and scale_size(), ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

I am trying to both edit the legend for the size aesthetic and set the scale size for that aesthetic, but can't seem to do both.

Here are the steps:

```
#create the map  
library(ggplot2)
world <- broders("world")

#generate a dataframe of geolocated data with attributes
points <- data.frame(lat = seq(0, 50, 10), 
                         lon = seq(0, 50, 10),
                         type = c("y", "n", "y", "n", "y", "n"), 
                         impact.x.r = seq(0, 50, 10))
points
lat lon type impact.x.r
1   0   0    y          0
2  10  10    n         10
3  20  20    y         20
4  30  30    n         30
5  40  40    y         40
6  50  50    n         50
```

I then map the points in ggplot - everything works:

```
ggplot() + 
  world + 
  geom_point(data = points, aes(x = lon, y = lat, col = type, size = impact.x.r)) + 
  scale_color_discrete(name = "types of birds", breaks = c("n","y"), labels = c("no", "yes")) +
  scale_size_continuous(name = "impact")
```

[image: working ggplot code]

However as soon as i try and set the scale size using: `+ scale_size()`, i get an error. I also lose the formatting that i did for the size aesthetic legend:

```
ggplot() + 
  world + 
  geom_point(data = points, aes(x = lon, y = lat, col = type, size = impact.x.r)) + 
  scale_color_discrete(name = "types of birds", breaks = c("n","y"), labels = c("no", "yes")) +
  scale_size_continuous(name = "impact") + 
  scale_size(range = c(0,15))

Scale for 'size' is already present. Adding another scale for 'size', which
will replace the existing scale.
```

[image: ggplot code broken by adding size_range()]

If i switch the order of the `scale_size_continuous()` and `scale_size()` calls, I still get the error. This way around I keep the formatting but lose the scale re-size:

```
ggplot() + 
  world + 
  geom_point(data = points, aes(x = lon, y = lat, col = type, size = impact.x.r)) + 
  scale_color_discrete(name = "types of birds", breaks = c("n","y"), labels = c("no", "yes")) +
  scale_size(range = c(0,15)) +
  scale_size_continuous(name = "impact")
 Scale for 'size' is already present. Adding another scale for 'size', which
will replace the existing scale.
```

[image: Another piece of broken ggplot code]

So its using the last call to scale_size...

But how do I amend the legend for the size aesthetic and set the scale_size to something that fits my map?

Comment: Do you just want to do `scale_size_continuous(range = c(0,15), name = "impact")`? You can only have one size scale. I don't quite understand why you need the second..

Comment: @Axeman: Yup, that solves it. Thanks for the simple answer. I hadn't realized scale was an option within `scale_size_continuous()`.